# Create folder in recently created folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, folder

I'm using the function below to create a folder and I'm trying to make it also create a subfolder within the newly created folder.

```
CreateFoldersbyparent("abc","")
CreateFoldersbyparent("abc","\test")

function CreateFoldersbyparent(name,parent,callback){
    var documentLibraryName = "Delte dokumenter";  
    var fileCollectionEndpoint = "https://gbas.sharepoint.com/Test/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + documentLibraryName + "')/folders/add(url=\'" + name + "\\" + parent + "\')";
    $.ajax({
        url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest":  window.top.$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("done")
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        //handle error...
                        console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is that it created 2 folders in the main root folder of "Delte dokumenter"(Shared documents in English)

What I desire:

```
-Delte dokumenter
   -abc
      -test
```

What it does:

```
-Delte dokumenter
   -abc
   -abctest
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
var createFolder = function(listTitle, folderUrl,success,error)
{
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var createFolderInternal = function(parentFolder,folderUrl,success,error)
{
   var ctx = parentFolder.get_context();
   var folderNames = folderUrl.split('/');
   var folderName = folderNames[0];
   var curFolder = parentFolder.get_folders().add(folderName);
   ctx.load(curFolder);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
     function () {
        if (folderNames.length > 1)
        {
           var subFolderUrl = folderNames.slice(1,folderNames.length).join('/');
           createFolderInternal(curFolder, subFolderUrl,success,error);
        }  
        success(curFolder);
     }, 
     error);
};
createFolderInternal(list.get_rootFolder(), folderUrl,success,error);
};
createFolder('DocumentLibraryName','Test/2017/12',
function(folder){
  console.log(String.format("Folder '{0}' has been created",folder.get_name()));
},
function(sender,args){
  console.log(args.get_message());
});

It will create folder structure as below:
Test
    |  
     2017
        |
         12
```

Answer (score 0):

Did update based on your code logic.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testCreateFolder() {
            CreateFoldersbyparent("abc", "MyDoc/").done(function () {
                CreateFoldersbyparent("test", "MyDoc/abc/");
            })
        }
        function CreateFoldersbyparent(name, parent, callback) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            var documentLibraryName = "MyDoc";
            var fileCollectionEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + documentLibraryName + "')/folders/add('" + parent+ name + "')";
            $.ajax({
                url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                headers: {
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("done");
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //handle error...
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
            return deferred.promise();
        }
    </script>
    <input id="Button1" onclick="testCreateFolder()" type="button" value="button" />
```